# How to change 'this' in jquery callback

Tags: jquery, plugins, this

I have written a jQuery plugin that takes a number in a div and then makes it count up.  I've tried to add a callback so when it finishes it then starts on the next div.

When it starts working on the next div it first resets the number in the current div, before carrying on on the next div as expected.  I suspect its something to do with using 'this' inside of the plugin.

[Here is a full (not) working example -->](http://codepen.io/sheepysheep60/pen/DnJit)

How do I prevent this happening? Thanks

My plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.countUp = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend( {
        'startFrom'     : 0,
        'countTo'       : Number(this.text()),
        'start'         : 10,
        'frequency'     : 200,
        'jump'          : 1,
        'target'        : this,
        'log'           : false,
        'callback'      : ''
    }, options);

    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    if(intRegex.test(settings.countTo) && intRegex.test(settings.startFrom) ) {
        // Both settings are integers, get started:
        if(settings.startFrom<settings.countTo){
            offset = settings.jump;
        }else{
            offset = -1 * settings.jump;
        }
        current_number = settings.startFrom;
        settings.target.html(current_number);

        checkNumber();
        var timer;
        function checkNumber(){
            if(offset<0){
                if(current_number <= settings.countTo)
                {
                    current_number = settings.counTo;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                        settings.callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current_number += offset;
                    timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
                }
            }else{
                if(current_number >= settings.countTo)
                {
                    current_number = settings.counTo;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                        settings.callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current_number += offset;
                    timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
                }
            }
            settings.target.html(current_number);
            if(settings.log){console.log(settings.target.attr('id'))};
        }   

    }else{
       if(settings.log){console.log('From countUp: Please use an integer for startFrom and countTo arguments.');}
    }
};
})( jQuery );
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#output").countUp({
        'log' : true,
        'callback' : call2
    });

    function call2(){
        $("#output2").countUp({
            'log' : true,
            'callback' : call3
        });
    }

    function call3(){
        $("#output3").countUp({'log' : true});
    }
})
```

Comment: The purpose of callback functions, is not to simply make your plugin do the same thing again. It's there so you can work with some temporary results as the plugin is working on something, or after it has finished an asynchronous task. To do what you want, you could just call the plugin 3 times in a row. But, let's say it is useful because the counting happens asynchronous. Then, for starters, try renaming callback to onFinished or something. Meaningful naming will help you understand much better what you are doing.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no need to add a parameter to `settings.callback.call(this);` You could just do `settings.callback()` if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: If I call the plugin 3 times in a row, they would all execute at the same time.  I'm trying to make the plugin execute one after another by using a callback, or onFinished function in the plugin to start the next animation.  I've done everything suggested, but the onFinished functions are still interfering with the previous div http://codepen.io/sheepysheep60/pen/jxudC

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I didn't notice the settimeout at first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the variables were being created from the settings, however they weren't being cleared.  By adding var infront of each of these variables, the scope stayed inside the function and fixed the issue.

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.countUp = function(options) {

var settings = $.extend( {
    'startFrom'     : 0,
    'countTo'       : Number(this.text()),
    'start'         : 10,
    'frequency'     : 200,
    'jump'          : 1,
    'target'        : this,
    'log'           : false,
    'callback'      : ''
}, options);

var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
if(intRegex.test(settings.countTo) && intRegex.test(settings.startFrom) ) {
    // Both settings are integers, get started:
    if(settings.startFrom<settings.countTo){
        offset = settings.jump;
    }else{
        offset = -1 * settings.jump;
    }
    current_number = settings.startFrom;
    settings.target.html(current_number);

    checkNumber();
    var timer;
    function checkNumber(){
        if(offset<0){
            if(current_number <= settings.countTo)
            {
                current_number = settings.counTo;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                    settings.callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                }
            }
            else
            {
                current_number += offset;
                timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
            }
        }else{
            if(current_number >= settings.countTo)
            {
                current_number = settings.counTo;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                    settings.callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
                }
            }
            else
            {
                current_number += offset;
                timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
            }
        }
        settings.target.html(current_number);
        if(settings.log){console.log(settings.target.attr('id'))};
    }   

}else{
   if(settings.log){console.log('From countUp: Please use an integer for startFrom and countTo arguments.');}
}
};
   })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable outside of the scope set to `this`

```
var $this = this;
```

That will fix the issue if I am reading the question correctly. `this` will be overwritten by the functions scope.

**UPDATE**

FYI, there is a typo in your code:

```
current_number = settings.counTo;
```

I assume it should be `settings.countTo` ?

**EDITED CODE**

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.countUp = function(options) {

    var $this = this;

    var settings = $.extend( {
        'startFrom'     : 0,
        'countTo'       : Number($this.text()),
        'start'         : 10,
        'frequency'     : 200,
        'jump'          : 1,
        'target'        : $this,
        'log'           : false,
        'callback'      : ''
    }, options);

    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    if(intRegex.test(settings.countTo) && intRegex.test(settings.startFrom) ) {
        // Both settings are integers, get started:
        if(settings.startFrom<settings.countTo){
            offset = settings.jump;
        }else{
            offset = -1 * settings.jump;
        }
        current_number = settings.startFrom;
        settings.target.html(current_number);

        checkNumber();
        var timer;
        function checkNumber(){
            if(offset<0){
                if(current_number <= settings.countTo)
                {
                    current_number = settings.counTo;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                        settings.callback.call($this); // brings the scope to the callback
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current_number += offset;
                    timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
                }
            }else{
                if(current_number >= settings.countTo)
                {
                    current_number = settings.counTo;
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    if (typeof settings.callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
                        settings.callback.call($this); // brings the scope to the callback
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current_number += offset;
                    timer=setTimeout(function(){checkNumber()},settings.frequency);
                }
            }
            settings.target.html(current_number);
            if(settings.log){console.log(settings.target.attr('id'))};
        }   

    }else{
       if(settings.log){console.log('From countUp: Please use an integer for startFrom and countTo arguments.');}
    }
};
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but is that not what `'target' : this,` is doing? Thanks

Comment: I guess I am unsure exactly what your plugin is aiming to accomplish. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you look at the link I provided, its just meant to count from 0 to the number in the div.  Then when it reaches that number start counting the next div from 0 to the number.  The link provided should end "10, 10, 10", but at the moment ends "1, 1, 10" when you run the script

Comment: I've made all suggested changes - there was a typo in there, thanks - but still the same issue http://codepen.io/sheepysheep60/pen/jxudC

Comment: You doubled up your callback, see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/barrychapman/V4Pbu/3/